# Fill Inputfield automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have a React application and in it I have an input field. I work with Bootstrap. When the user clicks a button, I want the input field to be filled automatically. So at the beginning it should be empty, because the variable `name = ""` and as soon as the button is pressed the name `Max` should be in the input field, how do I do that?

My Code

```
const Profile = () => {

const [name, setName] = useState();
const onClickBack = () => {
    setName('Max');
}


return (
    <div>

          <div className="form-group">
              <div className="col-xs-4">
                <label for="exampleInputName">Name</label>
                  <input
                         type="text"
                         className={name ? "form-control" : "form-control is-invalid"
                        }
                        placeholder={name}
                       onChange={(event) =>
                       setValueName(event.target.value)
                       }  
                       // text = {name} // not working                    
                                                    
                  />
             </div>
           </div>
           <button
              type="button"
              id="submit"
              name="submit"
              className="btn btn-primary submit-button ml-5"
              onClick={onClickBack}
               >
              Back
           </button>

    </div>
);
};

export default Profile;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's quite simple.** Use `value={name}` instead of  `text={name}`

```
 <input
      type="text"
      className={name ? "form-control" : "form-control is-invalid"}
      placeholder={name}
      value={name} 
      onChange={(event) =>
        setValueName(event.target.value)
      }
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `value={name}` if you want the state to be shown inside the `input` field.
Also I noticed that `setValueName()` is not defined anywhere, replace that with `setName()`.

Maybe you want to change the value of the input field to `Max` if the input field is empty when the user clicks the back button. In this case you should check if the input is not empty before setting a default name.

```js
const Profile = () => {

  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const onClickBack = () => {
    if (name !== '') {
      setName('Max');
    }
  }


  return ( 
    <div>
      <div className = "form-group">
        <div className = "col-xs-4">
          <label for="exampleInputName" value='Name'/> 
          <input type = "text"
            className = {
              name ? "form-control" : "form-control is-invalid"
           }
           placeholder={'Your name'}
           onChange = {
             event => setName(event.target.value)
           }
           value={name}                   
         />
       </div> 
     </div> 
     <button 
       type = "button"
       id = "submit"
       name = "submit"
       className="btn btn-primary submit-button ml-5"
       onClick={onClickBack}
     >Back</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `input` wrong.

```
<input
  type="text"
  className={name ? "form-control" : "form-control is-invalid"
  }
  placeholder={name}
  value={name}
  onChange={(event) =>
    setName(event.target.value)
  }
/>
```